# Transparent background in gnuplot multiplot

Tags: python, gnuplot

I'd like to get a transparent background in my gnuplot figure. 
What I coded till now is:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from numpy import *
import Gnuplot as gp
import Gnuplot.funcutils

x = (1,2,3)
y=(2,4,5)
x1 = (3,6,8)
g = gp.Gnuplot()
g("set terminal svg size 200,400")
g("set output 'filename.svg'")
g("unset xtics")
g("unset ytics")
g("set multiplot layout 3,1 title 'Title here'")
g("set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 fillcolor rgb '#ff0000'      behind")
#First
g("set tmargin 2")
g("set title 'Plot'")
g("unset key")
d = gp.Data(x,y,with_="lines")
g.plot(d)
#Secon
g("set title 'Plot2'")
g("unset key")
d1 = gp.Data(x1,y,with_="lines")
g.plot(d1)
#Third
g("set title 'Plot3'")
g("unset key")
d2 = gp.Data(y,x,with_="lines")
g.plot(d2)
g("unset multiplot")
```

I got a red screen but just the third plot. 
(Yeah, I have to change the rgb combo to get transparent background color. But, what's it?)

Thanks in advance, 
FB

Comment: What operating system are you using -- what svg viewer?  The above script works for me on Ubuntu linux with Eye of the Gnome as my viewr (if I remove the `set object` code).  Of course, you *can* make the background transparent by `set object 1 rectangle ... fillstyle transparent solid 0` (0-1 is the level of transparency, 0 being completely transparent)

Comment: Also, what version of gnuplot are you using?

Comment: Final question -- Is the end goal to have a given color show up behind all the plots?  If so, you can achieve that **without transparency** in any terminal that supports objects (I can easily modify your script to achieve that).

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your n-th advice. It is transparent if I use "eog", while it appears not transparent if I use "display" in shell. 
I'll try on my own script and I'll keep you up.

Comment: Just a quick word on `display` -- `display` is a wrapper around imagemagick routines which are created (primarily) for raster images.  `display` uses `gs` (ghostscript) to handle vector graphics (I think) and I've heard that ghostscript doesn't handle transparency correctly on file formats other than postscript (e.g. `pdf`, maybe `svg` also ... ).  So, I wouldn't trust that what you're seeing in `display` is what is actually in the file.

Comment: Thank you dude. I wanna send you the complete script you're useful for. Can you give your mail address or a way to send you what I've done?

Answer (score 9):

Gnuplot can output transparent backgrounds directly, but not for all formats.  For example, this can be done for .png:

```
set term png transparent truecolor
set output 'plot.png'
plot sin(x)
```

`transparent` handles the transparency for the background, and `truecolor` for transparent objects/plot fillings.

Another way I can get a transparent background out of gnuplot is if I output an .eps and convert it to .png or some transparency-supporting raster format.

Gnuplot example:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color
set output 'plot.eps'
plot sin(x)
```

In bash:

```
convert plot.eps -rotate 90 plot.png
```

The resulting .png has a transparent background where the .eps does not.  This may have to do with the way imagemagick handles transparency.  The same does not happen for me converting .svg to .png; it still has a white background.

You might have some luck using a vector graphics editor such as Inkscape to add transparency.

Comment: Gnuplot can do transparency in `png` files.  `set terminal png transparent truecolor` should do the trick (transparent handles the background while truecolor handles any other objects that may be transparent) -- or with pngcairo -- `set term pngcairo transparent`.  Doing it all in gnuplot will probably yield a sharper image than you would get from the conversion (especially with text)

Comment: You're right!  I updated my answer to include some of your comments.